# CodeIgniter - Project is main website

Tags: file, codeigniter, url, path, uri

This may be a potentially really, really dumb question.

So my CI project is going to be our main company website. I have created it here:

`www.example.com/CodeIgniter_2.1.3`

How do I get my users redirected to that when they just visit `www.example.com/` and have it stay `www.example.com` in the URL?

Is this a `.htaccess` file thing? Or do I need to move my folders up a level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter's default behavior is to hide it's actual path. You should only need to copy the .htaccess to the document root, and modify the path to include CodeIgniter_2.1.3

i.e:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have put the CI files in a directory called Codeigniter?

Comment: No. I've just called it that for simplicity in my explanation. But when you create a new CI project it all starts under one folder... Should I split it up?